# SFDX: ERROR: INVALID_OPERATION: rollbackOnError option must be true on a production org. When using Salesforce DX pre-release and Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I have a Visual Studio Code project which has beed authorised against a production environment.

I am using the Salesforce DX CLI pre-release:

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

When I right-click on an Apex class in Visual Studio Code and select:

```
SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR:  INVALID_OPERATION: rollbackOnError option must be true on a production org

How do I set `rollbackOnError` to `true` in the `sfdx-config.json` or `sfdx-project.json`?

Such that it's set correctly when I use the `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` command.

Comment: Looks like a bug/"unintentional feature" of `force:source:deploy`. I'm asking Wade for his input on the matter. The alternative workaround is `force:source:convert` followed by `force:mdapi:deploy` in order to set the necessary flag. I think it might literally be easier to write your own script for now.

Comment: @sfdcfox Any word from Wade?

Comment: I should circle back. He pinged someone else, and from there it just sort of fizzled out. Being #DF18 week, it might be a bit hard to get an answer though, but please remind me next Monday and I'll double-check.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry feel free to @ mention me here in the future. This is a known limitation that the team is addressing. We'll add these validation capabilities to the `force:source:deploy` command in the near future. For now, @sfdcfox's workaround is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

we had this issue when we set --ignoreerrors flag. Removed it and no issues any longer (note we use alias flags)
Before:
`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -u sfprod-c -d destructiveChangesPre -g -o -w 60 --apiversion '52.0'`
After:
`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -u sfprod-c -d destructiveChangesPre -g -w 60 --apiversion '52.0'`